# Using files as command line args Java

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass in two .wav files to my program through the command line.

In Main() I have tried casting them to be a File

```
File(args[0])
```

This don't work.If I want to be able to use the .wav files I pass in as command line args what do I need to do?

Comment: a nit... that's not a cast, that's constructing a File using the first command-line argument as a parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"?  What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in the url of the files via command line and then create new files from the urls.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file1 = new File(args[0]);
    File file2 = new File(args[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass files as command line arguments, you have to pass file names as command line arguments and open that file in main function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to open the files, remember that [`File`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html) in Java is an object that stores path and name information. Once you have created the file objects, you can use them to construct a [`FileInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) or one of its children.